# Installing InfluxDB on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, kubectl, kubeadm, kubernetes-helm

I was looking to quickly install InfluxDB on my Kubernetes cluster (built using kubeadm). This would just be a single pod running on a node (since non-enterprise InfluxDB doesn't support clustering). I was looking to persist the data to whatever node the pod is hosted on (i.e. hostPath solution that Kubernetes provides).

I am brand new to the Kubernetes world and looked online for some config files I could use to quickly generate an instance of InfluxDB but they all seem to revolve around Heapster which is not something I am looking for. I also attempted to install via Helm but was unable to get persistence working (when I enabled persistence the pod remained stuck in Pending state)

Any resources, configuration files, or help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need a little more information here. What infrastructure have you installed your cluster in? How many nodes? Do you have autoscaling?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Helm, it's a package manager for Kubernetes,

Here is the package of InfluxDB : https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/influxdb

=)

Answer (score 0):

The repo in the reply by Valentin Ouvrard is deprecated. The official influx helm charts are here: https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [InfluxDB Cluster](https://github.com/chengshiwen/influxdb-cluster)

The Helm chart is here: https://github.com/influxtsdb/helm-charts